# Доступ к объекту другого класса

Tags: c++-cli

Есть класс Source.h

```
#pragma once
#include "logic.h"

namespace tetstst {
    class Sourse{
    public:
        Sourse();
        logic player1;
    };
}
```

В Source.cpp идет присваивание объекту player1 параметров

```
#include "Sourse.h"

namespace tetstst {
    tetstst::Sourse::Sourse() {
        player1.setName("ARRA");
        player1.setScore(20);
    }
}
```

Сам класс logic выглядит так

```
#pragma once
namespace tetstst {
    class logic {
    private:
        int score;
        char* name;
    public:
        logic();
        void    setScore(int score);
        int     getScore();
        void    setName(char*);
        char*   getName();

        ~logic();
    };
}
```

А теперь к сути. Есть окно с textBox, в который нужно выводить значение `Score` у `player1`. Если в классе, в котором создаются элементы окна написать

```
textBox1->Text = player1.getScore();
```

то у меня ничего не выйдет. И в этом классе `player1` не доступен. Что нужно сделать?

Код MyForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Sourse.h"

namespace tetstst {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{
    public:
        MyForm(void){
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(104, 52);
            this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(264, 54);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->textBox1->TextAlign = System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Center;
            this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox1_TextChanged);
            this->textBox1->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(104, 125);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(124, 50);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->button1->Text = L"+1";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(244, 125);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(124, 50);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button2->Text = L"-1";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(474, 249);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Fucking nigger";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        /*textBox1->Text = "123";*/

    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    }
    private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    }
    private: System::Void textBox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e) {
        char number = e->KeyChar;
        if (!Char::IsDigit(number)){
            e->Handled = true;
        }

    }
};
}
```

Comment: А откуда вдруг в C++ взялся `textBox1`? Что это такое и какого оно типа? И какого типа `textBox1->Text`?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, но textBox был создан с помощью конструктора

Comment: Ну, у вас в коде нигде нет **объявления** этого самого текстбокса. Ну и я не вполне понимаю фразу «при помощи конструктора» — может, покажите код этого самого конструктора? (Ну и это конструктор какого класса?)

Comment: Если речь идет, "managed" с++, то player1.getScore() перед присвоением нужно преобразовать в "string"

Comment: Суть в том, что нельзя получить доступ к player1, он его просто не видит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае `player1` является переменной объекта класса `Sourse`, чтобы достать переменную `player1`, вам нужно создать объект класса `Sourse`.

Также ваши классы должен быть в виде cli классов.

```
public ref class Sourse{
    public:
        Sourse();
        logic player1;
};

public ref class logic {
private:
    int score;
    char* name;
public:
    logic();
    void    setScore(int score);
    int     getScore();
    void    setName(char*);
    char*   getName();

    ~logic();
};

Sourse^ sourse = gcnew Sourse();
textBox1->Text = sourse->player1.getScore();
```

Comment: Суть понял, но при добавлении `Sourse sourse = new Sourse();` начинает подчёркивать как ошибку `source` и выдавать ошибку "член класс управляемый не может относится к классу не управляемый"

Comment: ах, да, класс должен быть специальным для CLI, сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: Что-то снова пошло не так в виде подчеркнутого `gcnew` и ошибки "не существует подходящего определяемого пользователем преобразования из "tetstst::Sourse ^" в "tetstst::Sourse"

Comment: Хорошо, ещё поправил, попробуйте так, давно с cli не работал

Comment: Заработало, спасибо :D